# Payment Integration Using Firebase as a backend

Tags: android, firebase, payment-gateway

I want to integrate paytm wallet in my android app. I have used Firebase as my database so far. I have seen solutions where we have to host our own separate server for payment integration but is it possible to do it with firebase?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The payment gateways that I know of require that you specify a secret in your API calls. Since this can't be done securely from client-side code (which runs in your user's phone), it needs to be done from a trusted environment (e.g. your development machine, a server you control, or [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)).

There are great examples of integrating payments into Firebase with Cloud Functions in the [`functions-samples` repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples), for example [Stripe](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/stripe) and [Paypal](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/paypal). There is no sample of integrating paytm wallet, but you could probably use these examples as a starting point.

Your Firebase project will need to be on a paid plan for these to work, since these Cloud Functions call out to 3rd party APIs, which is not allowed on the free plan (to prevent abuse of the service).

Answer (score 1):

Their are a variety of payment gateways available where in few of them have server side code and few client side code.

The best and easiest integration of payment gateway with firebase as backend is [razorpay](https://razorpay.com/). They have a very easy documentation and can be integrated in just 30 mins of time.The developer documentation for the same can be found [here](https://razorpay.com/integrations/).

They support debit card,credit card and a few wallet payments as well.